# Change URL of button for 480 width Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, css, forms

I'd like to change the url of the button when they hit submit if they are on a mobile screen 480 width or less.

Example:

```
<form name="myform1" action="mylink.php" method="post"> 
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

But on mobile devices 480 wide or less I'd like it to change to:

```
<form name="myform1" action="mylink-mobile.php" method="post"> 
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

The page is PHP but I'm thinking I can use javascript screen.width to detect <= 480 but I'm not sure how to dynamically change the form action url based upon the screen width. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without JavaScript you can use CSS media to show and hide the different forms.

```css
form[name="myform1"] {
    display: block;  
}

form[name="myform2"] {
    display: none;  
}


@media (max-width: 400px) {

  form[name="myform1"] {
    display: none;  
  }

  form[name="myform2"] {
    display: block;  
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form name="myform1" action="mylink.php" method="post"> 
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form> 

<form name="myform2" action="mylink-mobile.php" method="post"> 
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you want to use JavaScript to change the action, you want to [read the window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: Thank you, an elegant solution to the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with no JavaScript at all.

```
<form name="myform1" class="wide sense" action="mylink.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
<form name="myform1" class="narrow sense" action="mylink-mobile.php" method="post"> 
  <input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

Include *both* forms with different `class` values. Then in your CSS:

```
form.sense { display: none; }
@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  form.sense.wide { display: block; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  form.sense.narrow { display: block; }
}
```

That'll work when a user goes from portrait to landscape without you having to monitor the orientation or screen geometry from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<form name="myform1" action="mylink.php" method="post"> 
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/Button1.jpg" border="0" alt="Submit" />
</form>
```

***JS***

```
window.onload = function (){
if (window.innerWidth <= "480")
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].setAttribute("action", "mylink-mobile.php");
}
```

Comment: Would the tag name be myform1 vs form in your example since there may be multiple forms on a page?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to detect if they're on a mobile device and act accordingly, right? After all, you're changing the form submission action, so I'm *assuming* something different is going on behind the scenes.

That said, I would go with mobile device detection instead of using the screen size. See this thread for more info (disregard the "jquery" part as the information provided has non-jquery solutions as well): [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

The majority seem to use user agent detection to determine if you're on mobile using something like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Mobi/)) {
    // mobile!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define two submit button with a different `value` attribute

```
<form action="action.php" method="post"> 
   ...
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="480" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="over480" />
</form>
```

and you show just one input, depending on the viewport size

**CSS**

```
[value="480"] { display: none; }
[value="over480"] { display: block; }

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    [value="480"] { display: block; }
    [value="over480"] { display: none; }
}
```

then in the `action.php` check which one actually submitted your form and — depending on that parameter sent via POST — apply a different server side logic.

**Pros:**

- no need to duplicate the markup of the form
- no need to use javascript to detect a size change of the viewport
- the server side logic is in one single entry point

---

Example (github gist):
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64b9e1d42c00356f5874

Comment: I like where you are going here, but I'm unclear how to tie the value to the action url. I'd like to send them to a mobile url when they submit the form if the max width is <= 480

Comment: try to check the value of `$_POST['submit']`, hopefully you should see either `480` or `over480`

Comment: @KeithW see https://gist.github.com/anonymous/64b9e1d42c00356f5874. depending on the value you call a script or another one